# CSS gets loaded when I press format in sources under developer console

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 and AWS

I am experiencing a strange issue with CSS loading in production.

- I load the home page, then things get loaded without proper application of custom styles
- When I inspect and go to the developer console and view the source of the particular CSS file and press format icon, styles get applied to the page.

Please help. Not sure how to fix this kind of issues.

`application.html.erb`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Explore various articles covering multiple domains.">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <title>Website</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico"/>


    <!-- Bootstrap 4 related scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta|PT+Sans|Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track'=> 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track'=> 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`_top_menu.html.erb`

```html
<div class="top-menu raisedbox">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/assets/logo.svg" width="100em" height="30" class="logo d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      Humbleposts
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link-text" href="/articles/index"><b>BLOG</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link-text" href="#"><b>RECENTS</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link-text" href="#"><b>ABOUT</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search for" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
<span class="empty-space">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Normally it would be as simple as ordering the stuff to load on the page. `1. head`, `1.1 Meta`, `1.2 Title`, `1.3 CSS`, `1.4 Rest of scripts and stuff`, `2. body`, `2.1 body content`, `2.2 Scripts and stuff`... Have you tested it in multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes. I tested in Chrome and Safari. Having an issue in both.

Comment: Tried the order you specified as well. Didn't work out.

Comment: Try copying your CSS very last on the page as well, so you will still have it in the head and very last within body tag (Just for testing

Comment: It is at the last currently.

Comment: Can you provide all your HTML? Sometimes elements aren't closed properly such as `div` or `script` and it can also prevent your page from being loaded correctly

Comment: Added in the post.